# wp_kses sanitization is deleting valid font family names

Tags: php, wordpress, sanitization

In WordPress, I have a string that I cannot control the contents of (user generated). For example let's say you have this:

```
$string = 'before <p class="test-class" style="font-family: &quot;Brush Script Mt&quot;;">text</p> after';
```

and then need to use wp_kses on it, but the style part gets completely removed:

```
$a = wp_kses( $string, array(
    'p' => array(
        'class' => array(),
        'style' => array()
    )
) );
var_dump(  $a ); // returns 'before <p class="test-class">text</p> after'
```

If you however remove the `&quot;` parts then wp_kses does work as expected:

```
$string = 'before <p class="test-class" style="font-family: Brush Script Mt;">text</p> after';
```

now it does output

```
$b = wp_kses( $string, array(
    'p' => array(
        'class' => array(),
        'style' => array()
    )
) );
var_dump(  $b ); // returns 'before <p class="test-class" style="font-family: Brush Script Mt">text</p> after'
```

I am unable to change the source font-family and it will always come with quotes around the font family name (") and I also need to use wp_kses on the string.

Is there any way to make wp_kses accept font-family with "?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't try to get `wp_kses()` to accept broken HTML. You should probably either replace the `&quot;` with a single quote (apostrophe) or just remove them.

If you were to get it to leave those quotes in you would wind up with:

```
before <p class="test-class" style="font-family: "Brush Script Mt";">text</p> after
```

Those nested quotes would break the HTML. Leaving the style attribute to be `style="font-family: "` and the rest being, hopefully, ignored by the browser.

So I would add in:

```
$string = str_replace( "&quot;",  "", $string );
```

Comment: That's a great approach.